# NSNotificationCenter in document-based app

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsnotificationcenter, nsdocument

I'm using `NSNotificationCenter` to send custom notifications in a document-based app.

A document-based app can have many open documents. Ideally, I would like the the document and its children to receive only the notifications created within the document or its children. In other words, a document should receive only the notifications that the same document generates.

At first I thought I could use the `notificationSender` parameter of [`addObserver:selector:name:object:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsnotificationcenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNotificationCenter/addObserver%3aselector%3aname%3aobject%3a) but then I realised that I don't always know which object will send the notification.

Do I have to check if I'm in the right document for every custom notification? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that your approach works if you  use the main document as `notificationSender` argument for both `addObserver:selector:name:object:` and `postNotificationName:object:`.

Comment: That's what I first tried. But if I do that I can't send the real sender (some object related to document that generates the notification).

Comment: @hpique: Perhaps you can use the `userInfo` parameter to pass the real sender?

Answer (score 2):

You can define a `NotificationCenter` in your `NSDocument` class and use that to post notifications within a document (Swift):

```
class Document: NSDocument {

    let notificationCenter = NotificationCenter()

    // Other stuff
}
```

And call it like this:

```
document.notificationCenter.post(name: yourNotificationIdentifier, object: nil)
```